# Display a DIV content centered in a page with a scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display a div:

```
<div class="detailcontainer" id="detailcontainer"></div>
```

Class:

```
.detailcontainer
{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-150px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:rgba(35,31,32,.7);
    z-index:60;
}
```

in the middle of a page with a scroll.

Actually, the div appears in the top of the page (visible here http://www.izigo.pt/Ad/GetAllByCategory?categoryId=1 and click in a car of the bottom of the list, it will appear in the top)

How can I open the detail of the car in the middle of the visible area?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
position:fixed;
```

instead of

```
position:absolute
```

It will keep it in view even if you scroll.

```
.detailcontainer
{
    position:fixed;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-150px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:rgba(35,31,32,.7);
    z-index:60;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8pCkT/1/)
(scroll down and press the click me)

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working and as you were the first to answer I have checked yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use position fixed instead of position: absolute;

Fixed works like absolute, but scroll does not affect the element.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working but @laaposto has answered first. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your container:

```
position: fixed;
```

This attribute means, that the `top`/`bottom`/`right`/`left`-values are calculated from the window-border, not the parent-element - it doesn't matter if you are scrolling, the container will always stay at its place.

**position: absolute:**
The `top`/`bottom`/`right`/`left`-values are relative to the body-tag (or any parent-tag with `position: relative`)

**position: relative:**
The `top`/`bottom`/`right`/`left`-values are relative to the place, where the element would be without that attributes.

Furthermore I recommend you cleaning up your css-code, and especially: **don't use style-tags**, only use css-files.

Comment: Hi thanks, it's working but @laaposto has answered first. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it with CSS. You need a little of JavaScript to do the job.

try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
    el = document.getElementsByClassName('detailcontainer')[0];
    divHeight = el.clientHeight;

    el.style.top = (winHeight - divHeight) / 2 + 'px';
}
```

Comment: This code is resizeing the div-container, but it's not centering it in the middle of the browser-window. But I think even resizing is possible without javascript, by just setting `top` and `bottom`, and ignoring the height-attribute (==> set automatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() +20+ "px");
        //this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }

    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#yourdivid').center();
        }, 500)
    });
```